# How to insert a Lead via Web-hook

Tags: rest-api, api, leads

I want to know the process of how we can insert Lead/Account/Opportunity via webhook i.e giving the URL to thirdparty application and third party will take care of rest to insert the data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solution to insert Lead in Salesforce.

1. You can use standard [**REST API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST/) to insert lead from your third party application to Salesforce. It also authenticate user using OAuth which makes it se
2. You can use Enterprise WSDL or parter WSDL to call [**SOAP API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/).
3. There are some third party API tools (Mulesoft) are also available which can be used as well.

SO it is all depends what is your use case it.

Comment: Himanshu Third Party Provider asked me to give a URL so that he can process it from their side to insert the Lead They call it webhook

Comment: in that case it is easy use case of REST API and insert the data.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to create a [Public RESTful REST Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html) (aka webhook). Full instructions are in the linked blog, but, in summary, assuming the third-party site wants to send you some JSON:

- Create an [Apex REST Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm). You can model the JSON that the third-party app wants to send by creating an Apex class with matching instance variables. [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) is a useful tool for this. Your Apex REST Method will need to create the relevant record and insert it.
- Add the Apex REST Method's class to the **Enabled Apex Classes** in the Site’s **Public Access Settings**.
- The public URL for an Apex REST Method has the format `{Site_URL}/services/apexrest/[optional-namespace]{URL_mapping}`. For example,  `https://patdevorg-developer-edition.na9.force.com/services/apexrest/myservice`
- Test from the command line with curl - e.g. `curl https://patdevorg-developer-edition.na9.force.com/services/apexrest/myservice?name=Burlington`
- To debug your webhook, turn on debug logging for the Site guest user, which will have a name like **SiteName Site Guest User**

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you can use web-2-lead feature of sfdc to create leads from websites.
You can read more from here:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm&language=en

Comment: Web to Lead form i know. my Third party provider asked me to give the URL so that he can use it form his Database and create a Lead.

I dont Know how to start with.